# How to access struct fields from an implemented trait function in Rust?

Tags: rust, struct, traits

So, following a tutorial online, I wanted to extend the functionality of a trait, Canine, using the `name` field from the struct the trait is implemented on:

```rust
struct Animal {
    name: String,
}

impl Animal {
    fn eat(&self) {
        println!("{} is eating", &self.name)
    }

    fn breathe(&self) {
        println!("{} is breathing", &self.name)
    }
}

trait Canine {

    fn bark(&self) {
        println!("Woof woof!");
    }
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("{} is running.", &self.name);
    }

}

impl Canine for Animal {}

fn main() {
    let rover: Animal = Animal {
        name: String::from("Rover")
    };

    // rover can do these as an animal
    rover.eat();
    rover.breathe();

    // rover can additionally do these as a canine
    rover.bark();
    rover.run();

}
```

This code works, with the exception of one component: the run() method under the Canine trait. The compiler error:

```rust
error[E0609]: no field `name` on type `&Self`
  --> src/main.rs:21:42
   |
15 | trait Canine {
   | ------------ type parameter 'Self' declared here
...
21 |         println!("{} is running.", &self.name);
   |                                          ^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0609`.
```

Why can I use &self.name in the method definitions of the basic impl for the Animal struct, but not in the Canine trait? What would be the proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. You have to define a getter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Canine` trait should define functions but not implementations, and then you put those implementations in the `impl Canine for Animal` block.

```
trait Canine {
    fn bark(&self);
    fn run(&self);
}

impl Canine for Animal {
    fn bark(&self) {
        println!("Woof woof!");
    }
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("{} is running.", &self.name);
    }
}
```

Now the compiler knows what `self.name` is, as that's clearly an `Animal`. In the original code it's not known what that is, as it's just a bare trait with zero context.

The alternative is to define some other trait like `Named` which can be used as a dependency:

```
trait Named {
  fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

trait Canine : Named {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("{} is running.", self.name());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I particularly like the alternative, is it allows a default implementation. i.e., there are no canine plants, only animals, so I want it to be clear that Canine would only ever be implemented for Animal structs.

Comment: Rust leans heavily into composition, so you might want to have a base `Creature` that you then `impl Animal` for, etc.

Comment: Makes sense. It also looks like there's both coherence and sealed traits, which are other approaches to this pattern:
https://rust-lang.github.io/chalk/book/clauses/coherence.html, https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/future-proofing.html#c-sealed